# jQuery .load() <img> no more in <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

i have a static html-page and some other files with same schema but other content.

```
    <div id="textRed" class="scrollbar">
       <h1>Header</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <a href="images/image1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="image-title" class="imgClass">
             <img src="images/image1_thumb.jpg" alt="image-title" />
             <br />
             Lorem Ipsum
          </a>
     </div>
```

i will load some new content to #textRed via .load(). everything works fine except the img-tag is after loading outside (after) the a-tag:

```
    <div id="textRed" class="scrollbar">
       <h1>Header</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <a href="images/image1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="image-title" class="imgClass">
             <br />
             Lorem Ipsum
          </a>
          <img src="images/image1_thumb.jpg" alt="image-title" />
     </div>
```

Also if i load the same file.

Here my (partial) js:

```
$(function(){
$('#aBtn').on('click', function(event){
    $('#textRed').load('newOrSameFile.html #textRed *', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
        if(statusTxt=="success")
            console.log('External content loaded');
        if(statusTxt=="error")
            console.log("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: i added the js to the question. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
$('#textRed').load('newOrSameFile.html #textRed *', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
```

Try this :

```
$('#textRed').load('newOrSameFile.html #textRed .imgClass', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
```

For Details of `.load()` see this link :- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Why? i need the complete content from #textRed

Comment: @DrEddison..the content is coming from 'newOrSameFile.html' not from #textRed....just give it a try it will work..

Comment: ok. i tried. the .imgClass ist loaded correct also with the img-tag. but i need also the h1 and the p. so i thought the * is the right selector for all element in #textRed because not every loaded new content file has an a- and img-tag.

Comment: @DrEddison..sorry but i didn't get you..as per your question the answer is correct..thanks..

Comment: @DrEddison..you are misunderstanding .load() just visit the link given in my answer..

Comment: I read that docu before i ask the question. could be that my english is not good enough to understand this correct. now i load in that way:
 $('#textRed').load('newOrSameFile.html #textRed h1, #textRed p, .imgClass', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) ...